# Reinstate data connection for data table

Tags: excel, unlink, data-connections

I got a data table that was accidentally unlinked and then saved.

Is there a way to reinstate the database connection without the table/sheet falling apart?

The sheet is heavily formatted and has a lot of columns that are calculated.

Comment: You can modify the connection on the table through VBA.

Comment: Is this the only way? I mean the connection is unlinked. How would I go about this? Just the regular way how I would normally modify a connection?

Comment: Yes.  You should be able to modify the `QueryTable` of the `ListObject`  I have to repair these very often for people.

Comment: I have problems getting it to work. `ws.QueryTables.Add ConnString, Selection, SQLQuery` does not work for me.

Comment: I tried some more things and none of them seem to work out. The table exists already, the connection was unlinked. I am not sure if any of those two facts make a difference.

Comment: `Worksheet.ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Connection`...etc.

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well, that does not work. I used `Worksheet.ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Connection = ConnString`

Comment: You also have to reenter the `CommandText` and all of the other attributes of the `QueryTable`.  Honestly, if you're struggling this much you should just delete the table a recreate it.  It will take far less time.

Comment: No, it will not save me time. The sheet is massive. The problem is that when you unlink there is no way to recover. I would be really keen to see a VBA solution to this problem because I have yet to see one on the internet.

Comment: The massiveness of the sheet doesn't really factor into recreating a `ListObject`.  The entire point of this construct is to be able to do exactly this.

Comment: So I cannot reinstate the connection? Will an added querytable delete everything?